# Redmi Note 11 forgotten password

Tags: lock-screens, locked-out, redmi-note-11

I have a Redmi Note 11 phone with a lock screen password set by someone who has now forgotten it.

I have tried the steps it says on the phone by holding the power button along with the volume-up buttons. When the next screen comes up, there is no wipe data option. When you select safe mode, it just boots back up to the password screen. The Redmi PC suite is in all Chinese, and after struggling to change the language to English, it says that the phone isn't connected.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try Samsung support.  Or see if one of the techies in the mall can do something.  Otherwise I don't think that you can do very much.  Its' a security feature.

Comment: @RohitGupta "Redmi" is a Xiaomi sub-brand.